# How to add TextView's programatically to a ScrollView with a LinearLayout and existing TextViews

Tags: android, scrollview

I have the following:
-A map with Strings like:["Color: blue","Size: big"] called detailsArray

An existing ScrollView with a LinearLayout and existing TextViews:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:text="something: else"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've ommited common fields like width, height, xml schemas on purpose.

Now I want to add textViews programmatically.
I don't know hoy many are they:

```
    TextView detail;
    LinearLayout llay = (LinearLayout)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.container);    
    for (int i = 0; i < detailsArray.length; i++) {
                    detail = new TextView(fragmentView.getContext());
                    detail.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    detail.setText(detailsArray[i]);
                    llay.addView(detail);
                }
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        sv.addView(llay);
```

But I'm getting an exception:

```
04-17 12:38:09.975: E/AndroidRuntime(3361): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I solved it with a single line of code before adding the to the LinearLayout:

sv.removeAllViews();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `sv.addView(llay);` as you are basically adding the linear layout twice to the same **ScrollView** - that the exception you are getting and why when you removeAllViews in the beginning it solves the issue.
After you finish the for loop call

```
sv.invalidate(); 
sv.requestLayout();
```

should make it refresh it's content.